# PHP AD authentication using only 3 random characters from password

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I have a website, logging users in if they successfully authenticate with their Active Directory password. Many allow the browser to save the password. 
What I want to do, is request only certain characters from the password... much like banking systems do.

ie. Please enter character   2    5    and 7 from your password.

Is it possible to do this in PHP? I've google searched, but I'm not convinced I know the term to search for.

Any pointers in the right direction will be gratefully received. 
Thanks.

Comment: The password is a string. Read more about PHP [strings](http://php.net/language.types.string). Focus on the section ["String access and modification by character"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr)

Comment: thanks for the pointer. I've read through that and already know that information. What I'm trying to do is authenticate with an LDAP request from PHP, but not sure that LDAP / AD will even allow this kind of authentication.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this wouldn't be possible with LDAP or AD. To support users logging in with certain characters of their password (assuming you're not storing the password as plain text), you need to store a hash of each password, and verify the requested characters against those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done, not in AD, in PHP, but it would **most likely compromise your users passwords**.

You would have to save and securely hash each password character separately so you can compare the given characters against saved one-character hashes.

It should be done so that not even the length of users password would be compromised (save up to *n* hashes even though most of them come from empty characters).

Even though you'd do all that, hashing single character is a disaster for security as brute-force cracking a single character takes a blink of an eye even when using a generally safe hashing algorithm.

Given that your users authenticate through Active Directory (LDAP, I guess?), I wouldn't say this is a reasonable approach as you have limited knowledge about passwords, their changes (to be able to recalculate hashes) etc.

Comment: Thanks very much for a detailed and useful answer to my question. Perhaps I'll combine the two and continue the usual AD authentication but set up a 2nd level password alongside, which I can use the above approach with. Many thanks.